# azure ad app registrations - one allows me to add Azure Role Assignments to a managed id, another doesn't

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-app-registration

I have manually created 2 different azure app registrations.  From what I can see, they are the same.
However, when I try to use them to programmatically run a powershell script that assigns Azure Roles to a managed ID, one works and the other fails.

So specifically I'm trying to add 3 roles to:

Azure Portal Home -> MyResourceGroup -> MyManagedId -> Azure Role Assignments.

The roles are:

- Storage Table Data Contributor
- Azure Service Bus Data Owner
- Storage Queue Data Contributor

From what I can see about the app registrations:

- Both are owners at the subscription level.  (Subscriptions -> Access Control(IAM))
- Both have fresh secrets created
- both have these permissions listed under the "API permissions" section:

| PermissionName | Type | Admin consent required |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy | Application | Yes |
| AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All | Application | Yes |
| User.Read | Delegated | No |

When I try to run my script that assigns the roles, app reg 1 works.  I end up with the storage account roles I need.  When I use app reg 2, it fails with the error:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
        "details": [{
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"InvalidPrincipalId\",\r\n    \"message\": \"A valid principal ID must be provided for role assignment.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
        }, {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"InvalidPrincipalId\",\r\n    \"message\": \"A valid principal ID must be provided for role assignment.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

Here's the script:

```
#Load Environment variables that drive this script. 
$currentEnv = (Get-Content './vars.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)

az cache purge

az login `
     --service-principal `
     --username $currentEnv.AZ_DEPLOYMENT_CLIENT_ID `
     --password $currentEnv.AZ_DEPLOYMENT_CLIENT_SECRET `
     --tenant $currentEnv.AZ_TENANT_ID `
     --allow-no-subscriptions

#set the subscription we want to use
az account `
     set --subscription $currentEnv.AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID

az resource list `
     -g $currentEnv.AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME `
     -o table


#look up the app function name for this resource group
$AZ_FUNCTION_APP = az functionapp list `
    -g $currentEnv.AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME `
    -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-output $AZ_FUNCTION_APP.Name

$MANAGED_ID_DISPLAY_NAME = $AZ_FUNCTION_APP.Name + "-userId"
Write-output $MANAGED_ID_DISPLAY_NAME + " is the name of the managed identity"

$objectid=$(az ad sp list --display-name $MANAGED_ID_DISPLAY_NAME --query [].objectId --output tsv)
Write-output $objectid

az deployment group create `
    --resource-group $currentEnv.AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME `
    --template-file "./arm_templates/rbac-role.json" `
    --parameters `
    principalId=$objectid `
    builtInRoleType="['StorageQueueDataContributor', 'StorageTableDataContributor','AzureServiceBusDataOwner']"
```

The line that the script is actually dying on is this:

```
$objectid=$(az ad sp list --display-name $MANAGED_ID_DISPLAY_NAME --query [].objectId --output tsv)
```

When I google this error, I see articles that state that the app reg must be either an owner or be a User Access Administrator.
I've tried to add "User Access Administration" rights to the app reg 2 that fails.  But it makes no difference.

Here's a screenshot showing the Subscription roles.  The registration that works is the one that ends in lowercase "bi".  The one that fails is the one that has "BI-Deploy" as a part of the name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be the use of "-" as part of the name.

Try changing the name.

Next Idea:

Have you created a managed identity for both apps?

Comment: both app registrations have "-" in the names.  But i'll remove all "-"'s from the failing app reg and try again.

Comment: no dice.  same errors even after removing all hyphens from the app registration name.